# AutoCAD error in Array Command

Tags: autocad

I'm studying AutoCAD. It's the version of 2017. Now I gonna utilize Array Command.

Unfortunately, the Array Command doesn't work in the AutoCAD. Whether I type it in the command line or select it from Modify part.

Please take a look at the attachment.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[The photo of the error in command line](https://ibb.co/dKuymv)

Comment: provide your related code so that others know how to help you.

Comment: @UmarZaii what is related code?

Comment: Your code for the array. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know how to ask a good question.

Comment: you want ARRAYCLASSIC. Also, this is a programming forum, not a user forum. See the forums listed at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info

Answer (score 0):

The DEMANDLOAD variable value is set to 0.

Change the value to 3.

From http://support.a2ktechnologies.com.au/Knowledgebase/Article/View/340/2/autocad-basic-commands-not-working---demandload